# Where is the "update site" list stored in the filesystem?

Tags: linux, eclipse

**Updated2**: Where is the list of *software sites* stored in the filesystem?  I am after the **file** where this information is stored.

Eclipse Galileo 3.5 won't let me delete broken *software site repositories* from the list. E.g. I am trying to get rid of the Bazaar Update Site.

Comment: You don't need to put tags in the subject, SO has an excellent tag system.

Comment: I see you've meanwhile accepted, but you may want to look at some information I've included in a recent update of my answer. Perhaps you'll find something in there helpful.

Comment: @Fredrik: it is for people reading the questions on the site's portal:   I believe in visual cues/shortcuts to get people's attention.

Comment: @jldupont: I don't know what you refer to with "site's portal" but the tags on SO is very visible all over SO. You are right it makes your posts stand out, but not in a good way (and considering you have 11.4k rep it surprises me that you haven't noticed the norm).

Comment: @Fredrik: it is my "marketing side" that shows up :-) I'll be more careful from now on. Cheers.

Comment: @jldupont: Btw, I didn't mean to be offensive. It was intended more as a kind suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l "xxx.googlecode" "{}" \;
```

in directory `~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins`

to find occurrences of an SVN provider I have registered. I came up with

```
./org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.team.svn.core.prefs
./org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/Jospital/.indexes/properties.index
```

That should get you off to a running start. Locations may vary depending on what  version control plugin you use.

---

**Update: Software update sites**

Oh I see, I misunderstood "software update site" for "source control site".

I did a similar search from the directory where I have Eclipse installed and found:

```
./eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/epp.package.jee.profile/.data/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.prefs
./eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/epp.package.jee.profile/.data/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.prefs
```

... which is in line with the information other people have been posting too.

---

**Update: the button click problem**

A lot of people are finding that "things don't work" in Eclipse, and it turns out that what is not working is clicking on some buttons. Maybe you just weren't able to activate the <kbd>OK</kbd> button when doing the <kbd>Remove</kbd>?

This problem will be fixed in the next release of Eclipse. For the meantime, there is a workaround, nay 2:

- You can click a button using the space bar on the keyboard;
- You can follow the advice given [on my blog](http://wondersofcomputing.blogspot.com/2009/11/eclipse-button-clicks-in-ubuntu-910.html) and many other places. It involves defining an environment variable for Eclipse.

**Update: Another workaround**

If certain software sites are bothering you with frequent failed attempts to update and you are unable or unwilling to remove these sites from your list of available sites, you could also just simply <kbd>Disable</kbd> them in Eclipse's GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your time Carl: I updated the question to reflect a better appellation for what I am after.

Comment: THANKS a million! You saved my day re: button issue!

Answer (score 4):

From the menu:

Windows --> Preferences --> Install/Update --> Available Software Sites

Comment: Thanks for your time Jason: maybe my question isn't sufficiently clear (and I apologize for this): I am after the location of the **file** which contains the update sites. You see, Eclipse won't let me delete sites from the GUI anymore... something is really broken.

Answer (score 2):

Those sites should also be referenced in

```
eclipse\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\epp.package.java.profile\.data\.settings\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.prefs\
  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.prefs
  org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.prefs
```

and also in [other directories](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.pde/msg01866.html), which can be a problem for non-Administrator Windows users, as see in the [bug 282740](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=282740), duplicated of [bug 249133](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=249133)

Comment: +1: useful related links... but I am not interested in Windows related issues.

Comment: @jldupont: the second bug (249133) is also for Linux distributions.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the files you are looking for are the XMLs in

```
<eclipse>\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache
```

Comment: seems like the place... thanks!  One note though: it seems there aren't just *xml* files in there but also *jar* files containing the *xml* files in question.

Comment: My guess is that the jar file contains the default, as-shipped version of the XML file. The file has to come from somewhere, right?